# Issue with negative lookahead in bash regex on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file that has tokens in french, each seperated by a newline. The file is called fr_notime.txt and looks like following:

```
bonne-chance
d'
être
l'
heureux
élu
»
,
écrit
-
il
sur
sa
25
```

I want to lose the punctuation and digits, but without losing the contractions as in `d'` or compound words as in `bonne-chance`, thus using a hyphen or dash in between the same.

My solution was to read the file line-by-line and depending upon its content, process it. I wrote the following as a .sh script-

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
    if ( [[ $line =~ "[[:alpha:]]+'|-[[:alpha:]]+" ]] );
        then
          echo "$line : .............................................Exception"
        elif ( [[ $line =~ "[[:punct:]0-9]" ]] );
          then
            echo "$line : 11111111111 Digit or Punct"
          else
            echo "$line : Regular"
        fi
done < "fr_notime.txt"
```

Q1. This is just a basic script to know if I am filtering them correct, but somehow it just returns `Regular` for every token. Is there something I am missing?
PS- I tried removing ; after the if segment, but to no avail.
**This part was solved, after removing double quotes in the sh file. However, Q2 still remains unanswered.**

Q2. While trying to use grep and perl regex to solve it on command line, I used the following code-

```
grep -P "(?![[:alpha:]]+'|-[[:alpha:]]+)[[:punct:]0-9]" fr_notime.txt | less
```

The command always returns as no match found.

I might be wrong but there should be a common element to both of these. What am I doing wrong and/or missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Deleting double quotes worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, the grep bit is still buggy.

Comment: Are you perhaps overthinking it?  Why not use grep -Ev '[[:alpha:]]' file, so you are saying only show me lines with no alpha characters?  Note: you can use the same approach in bash  Also, I prefer to place my regexes in a variable in bash and then use it unquoted.  I have had the least amount of impact using this method.

Comment: @grail The solution you proposed actually works better. I think I was looking at it too hard, overthinking it in the process. The approach I used originally ignores some of the checks, but the one you suggested works way better at the same. Thanks a lot for the same.

Comment: However, there is a trade off. While it catches more number of samples, it also adds 'jargon'. I called the command you mentioned and the original one, calling a diff between the two in that order. This is something I saw-
`915a965
> g4
923a974
> d'
951d1001
< €
958a1009
> aujourd'hui
1018a1070`

As evident, it catches more examples, but also adds jargon like g4, which is not something required. How do I tackle this?

Comment: Calling another `grep -Pv '[[:digit:]]' file` after the `grep` command @grail posted solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I love using perl regex syntax;

```
grep -vP "^\s*\d+\s*$|^\s*\W+\s*$" fr_notime.txt
bonne-chance
d'
être
l'
heureux
élu
écrit
il
sur
sa
```

The regex explained.  Two patterns being searched; both use ^ for the start of the line and $ for eol, and \s* to trap any whitespace.  \d+ finds one or more digits, and \W+ finds one or more non word, non whitespace chars.   grep options, -v inverts the match, and -P tells grep to use perl syntax.

-Cheers